# Can We assign a null value to an Master Detail relationship?

Tags: apex, relationships, master-detail

Can We assign a null value to an Master Detail relationship? It is required by default and hence while inserting to database it comes as Required Value missing?
And if I try to insert some dummy value it says Id type mismatch.

Actually I have two custom Objects and using same controller and page to manage both objects but while using one other I have to give as null to other so that one can be save with value and other can be saved with null.

Answer (score 6):

If you would read the description of a Master-Detail field, you would notice the following:

> Creates a special type of parent-child relationship between this object (the child, or "detail") and another object (the parent, or "master") where:
>
> - **The relationship field is required on all detail records.**
> - The ownership and sharing of a detail record are determined by the master record.
> - When a user deletes the master record, all detail records are deleted.
> - You can create rollup summary fields on the master record to summarize the detail records.
>
> The relationship field allows users to click on a lookup icon to select a value from a popup list. The master object is the source of the values in the list.

If you want a child record without master, try considering a Lookup relationship or create a dummy Master record to attach your detail records to it. Do not forget to re-attach it to the actual master record when you are done

Answer (score 2):

It is a MUST field, you cannot skip if the relationship is Master-Detail.

The alternative that you can do is create a DUMMY Master record (say PLACEHOLDER) and assign this for the Detail records.  This way, you can proceced further and later decide what you can do with these child records.

Comment: Actually the page and controller is used by two objects so while using for one ,,i m giving a valid value to the master-detail but i don't need to filled it while using other object as it has it's own relation..is there any way of giving a dummy values or i have two write separate page and controller.

Comment: cannot comment without seeing your code.  Would be better if you create a question with your code posted and seeking exact issue with the code

Answer (score 0):

As you're suggesting that your page is designed to work with 2 different custom sObjects, and if it's not possible for you to break it down to 2 pages, one for each sObject, I think you can handle it in the logic by conditionally rendering panels and/or other components.

Otherwise, a better way would be to create a custom component with the common portion of the page and using it in the 2 pages you would create for the 2 sObjects mentioned.